# body and (*) Properties in css

Tags: html, css

Are `body` properties and `*` properties different?

I always use `body` and `html` properties the same way. Can I use `*` properties with `body` and `html`?
And what should be different in `*` versus `body` properties?
I don't understand why it is necessary to use both these properties?

If I use one of them does it create any problems?

I use this

```
    *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background:#FFF;
    }
```

and in body

```
    body, html{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background:#FFF;
        font:normal 12px verdana;
        color:#0086ca;
    }
```

when I use `body, html` it changes the background. When I remove `background` from `*` it didn't change bg color.

Comment: There are no different `*`, `html` or `body` properties. Can you give an example of different css rules?

Comment: Can you show some examples? Also, what specific use case do you have for `*`?

Comment: @kobi, pekka i have edit my question.

Comment: in my condition is this necessary to use both properties * and body?

Comment: If you want that all your elements will have those attributes so yes (use asterisk).
If you want only body to have those attributes so no.

Comment: @cthulhu.i think * properties apply on all element.this also effect to link and  hover properties.

Comment: @kc rajput
that's what i said. take a look at my answer. * Applies to ALL elements in your page. IF you set margin in * for example, than all other elements will get the same value of margin. So i think it's better for you not to use the *.

Comment: @cthulhu ya you are right. i have use this and this is good for me.

Comment: I consider using `*` a bad practice, especially for resetting margins and paddings. Reset CSS stylesheets are a better option (for example http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ ), if you need one (I generally don't but that's another story). And it's not because you find `* {margin:0; padding:0;}` on a lot of sites that it isn't a bad practice :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` (Asterisk) - It is a wildcard, this means it will select all elements within that portion of the DOM.
It's a universal rule which affect on every element.
for example:

Margin every element on the page

```
* {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

**All** HTML components will have those attributes.

Body affects only on the body tag...The elements within the tag aren't affected - (they are not getting the same attributes.)

Comment: Priority> and if two instructions with the same property are defined for both `*` and `body` (or any other element), than the one defined for the element will have a higher priority (more weight) and its value will appear.

Answer (score 2):

`body` applies to the `<body>` tag, while `*` applies to *every* tag. An example of the difference can be seen in the following:

```
body { margin: 2cm; }
```

versus

```
* { margin: 2cm; }
```

The first gives the body a margin – the second gives *every* element a margin.

On the other hand, the following code:

```
body { font-family: Courier; }
```

will change the font family in the whole document since CSS uses *cascading* styles, i.e. nested tags inherit certain style properties from their parents – in this case, the font.

Answer (score 2):

Using `*` in CSS matches any element. Using it alone is rarely useful, because you will target every element in the page.

If you for have html code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
  body { font-size: 50px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      Name: <input type="text"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The font size set for the body will affect the text "Name:", but it will not affect the font size of the input element, as it has a specific size set by default.

If you now add the style `* { border: 10px solid red; font-size: 100px; }` this will put a border on the body, div, form and input elements, and both the text and the input element will get the font size.

The `*` selector is more useful in combination with other selectors, like selecting any child element to a specific element:

```
#Menu > * { float: left; }
```

Regarding what to use for the html and body element, you only need to set the margin, padding and background for the body element.

Comment: @kc: No, it's certainly not neccesary. It's rarely used, and when it's used it's mostly for css hacks (the * html hack). I have never used it for anything myself.